# Complication: Clone of an Evil-Doer

Tags: character-creation, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

We have a player that wants to be the good-aligned clone of Mina Kosmova, the [Cosmic Mind](http://mutants-masterminds.wikia.com/wiki/The_Cosmic_Mind). I'm trying to work with the player and so far, we've come up with nothing. What sort of sample complications would be the result of a character with such an origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of [options](http://www.d20herosrd.com/character-creation/#OTHER_COMPLICATIONS) that spring to mind. In no particular order:

- Fame: The villain is famous and the hero is easier to locate. If the player wants the character to be hounded by detectives, reporters, and law enforcement then this is a pretty good choice.
- Prejudice: Lots of folks freak out about clones. That can manifest in game as suffering prejudice.
- Reputation: Mistaken for Kosmova. Most characters treat the hero like that particular villain.
- Rivalry: With the villain.
- Secret: If the character has managed to keep the connection unknown up to the campaign start. This will probably transition to one of the others at some point.
- Temper: Being mistaken for the villain. A nice call out to some biological reasons the villain went evil.

Good luck!

Comment: Would you also think that this would also be good complications: Quirk-Naive: Limited life experience outside of a lab.

Comment: @MnIce That could work, but is independent of the question. Real cloning takes as much time as raising a non clone, so the character is no more likely to be naive than anyone else that can hear the thoughts of the people around her. Even comic book clones are only naive if they can't read the minds of all around them. Amazo (robot, not clone, but illustrative) turned on Luthor as soon as he had Martian Manhunter's telepathy. ;)

Comment: Hey, how would you implement the Secret Complication for the character if they had either a secret or public identity?

Comment: @MnIce The Secret would be that the character was a clone of Kosmova. How that's still secret is a big part of how I'd make that a complication, and beyond the scope of this question. Still, I'd have various NPCs periodically show up, trying to discover, prove, or reveal the connection, just like any other Secret.

Comment: What's funny is that the player didn't want to play a Mind Reader/Psychic/ Whatever, she's playing the Gadgeteer. She literally just picked the most intelligent villain she could find.